# XCUITest set running on both macOS and iOS

Tags: ios, xcuitest

We are building an app using Catalyst and I need to run UI tests on both iOS and macOS. However, in the iOS/iPadOS there are gestures (swipes, long press etc.), which are not present on macOS. So, when I try to build tests on macOS, it fails with the errors like *"Value of type 'XCUIApplication' has no member 'swipeDown'"*.

Does anyone have any ideas about what to do to keep one set of tests for both macOS and iOS?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swipes are unavailable for macOS, because macOS doesn’t run on touchscreen devices.

You can still reuse your code if you separate elements, steps and tests code with ScreenObject (aka PageObject) pattern.

Search the internet for more documentation. You can also check out my implementation of this pattern here
https://github.com/rzakhar/xctest-assignment

Your steps can be multiplatform if you use @available or #if APIs

```swift
#if os(iOS)
    cell.swipeLeft()
    cell.buttons["Delete"].tap()
#else
    cell.buttons["More"].click()
    cell.buttons["Delete"].click()
#endif
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your comment! I have already separated page objects, step definitions and test scenarios. However, some of step definitions contain gestures. e.g. If test is about deleting or re-naming element you have to use long tap or swipe to see the context menu with delete or re-name buttons. So looks like I have to create one more UITest target for macOS and have to duplicate most of the code. That's what I am want to avoid.

Comment: Try @available APIs or #if syntaxis. Added an example in my answer.

Comment: Roman, thanks a lot! That is exactly what I was looking for!